# How To Make A motor timer with Solar Panel

Tags: motor, dc, solar-cell, timer

I need to figure out how to make a 763RLN, 667RN Nutone Fan Motor rotate twice a day.  The motor is powered via a  TOOGOO(R) 1.5W 12V Mini Solar Panel. The idea is that we have a EXP1250 12V 5Ah Home Alarm Battery supply that will build up charge over the day by the solar panel and then reach a certain amount of power for the motor to run for 30 seconds on a low turning speed. What I need to know is how to possibly build or buy a timer that would allow my group to do this. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Shopping questions are off-topic for this site.

Comment: i hope that you realize that `rotate twice a day` means 1 revolution per 12 hours .... i think that you want `run twice a day`

Comment: what does the motor turn?

Answer (score 1):

3100 RPM 1.0 amps 120V 60hz  is the spec for the fan , not 12Vdc.

There are many sources of digital clock timers to turn on an AC outlet.  All programmable for many start/stop times